# 'DataFrame' object is not callable, how do i solve it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, libraries

I'm new to pandas please help to solve this error. I'm using Jupyter to program. Here's snapshot:
[image]

Comment: In the future, please copy the raw text instead of taking a screenshot. Links to images can break (however unlikely it seems) and text allows editors to help make your question more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `()` instead of `[]`

```
df[df['CustomerID'].notna()]
```